# Have trouble retrieving height property from css file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Everyone.

I am pretty much sure that the answer to my question is relatively easy.

I have a .css file that has following code:

```
div.site
{
  text-align:center;
  border:2px solid #4b6c9e; 
  padding:1px;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-size:medium;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-weight:bold;
  height:25px; 
}
```

Then, I have an a .js file that builds my `div` from xml. Here is a fragment:

```
txt = txt + "<div class='site'><span class='link'><a class='nav' href=' " + siteUrl[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "' target='_blank'>" + siteName[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</a></span></div>"

document.getElementById('portalLinks').innerHTML = txt;
```

My .html file has the following:

```
<div id="portalLinks"></div>
```

I have no problem displaying the data on a page. What I have trouble with is 
getting the height for `site` class from my .css file. I am using the following code:

```
var height = $(".site").height();
```

What I want to do is to use this `height`, to dynamically calculate the height for `portalLinks`:

```
$("#portalLinks").css({ "height": newHeight }) - where newHeight will be calculated based on `height`
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: What result you get? What result you expect?

Comment: I got 25 pixels height from your code. Are you sure you call inside `$(document).ready(`  event handler?

Comment: When trying to display the height's value with alert(height), I get null

Comment: That means you are calling code before elements are added to the DOM

Comment: I finally got it. Thank's a lot to all of you for your input. My problem was that in my method, I was trying to get the height of `site` first and then to actually build the content. That's why I could not get the value of the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the value returned from `$(".site").height();` is not a complete CSS height value. It is only a number.

Calling `$("#portalLinks").css({"height": newHeight})` with the result of your first call will set an invalid value of 25. You'll want to attach a unit to the variable -- in this case, `px`:

```
$("#portalLinks").css({"height":newHeight+'px'});
```

Also, it is worth mentioning that this call alone will set the height of `#portalLinks` to the height of **one** `.site` element.

If you want to set the height to the combined total, you will need to iterate through the results of `$('.site')` somehow:

```
var newHeight = 0;
$(".site").each(function(){
    newHeight += $(this).height()
});

$("#portalLinks").css({"height":newHeight+'px'});
```

See this fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/EZWX4/

---

**Other Notes:** `.height()` returns the value of the CSS `height` attribute. It does not account for padding and/or borders.

This could cause some display problems in some cases, so you should consider using `outerHeight()` instead.

Also: using `outerHeight(true)` will include the defined margins in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("#portalLinks").css("height", newHeight);
```

Also, use this to get the height:

```
var height = $(".site").outerHeight(); // includes the stroke width
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, guys. Thank's a lot to all of you for your input. My problem was that in my method, I was trying to get the height of `site` first and then to actually build the content. That's why I could not get the value of the height. So, basically that's what I did to dynamically build my html:

```
        var height = $(".site").height();
        var margin = $(".site").css("margin-top");
        var newHeight = (height * site.length) + (margin * site.lenght);

        $("#portalLinks").css({ "height": newHeight + "px" });
```

That perfectly worked in my case.